# What is the best way to differentiate between a photo and clipart without ML?

Tags: image-processing, python-imaging-library

I have a lot of images that are either a photo or logo/clipart/drawing/etc. I'd like to find a way to programatically separate photos from the rest. Is there a way to do that relatively reliably without using ML?

**Examples:**

*Logo*

[image]

*Photo*

[image]

Comment: Please clarify. What is ML?

Comment: @fmw42 *"Machine Learning"* I assume. Congrats on 20k points - you now have the *"Freedom of the City"* 

Comment: Thanks for both, Mark Setchell.

Comment: Clip art often has lots of white or solid regions of color or limited number of colors. Real photos do not.

Answer (score 1):

The two examples you have chosen are easily differentiated by the number of colours. The logo has 584 and the photo has 2 orders of magnitude more at 51,811.

Also by entropy.

Normal colour photos also don't have an alpha/transparency channel which is much beloved by graphics designers when making logos, so you could test for that too.

Check for alpha, count colours and measure entropy with any Python/C++ library or **ImageMagick**:

```
magick identify -format "%f: %[type]: %k: %[entropy]\n"  logo.png photo.jpg
logo.png: TrueColorAlpha: 584: 0.166973
photo.jpg: TrueColor: 51811: 0.917643
```

If still using v6 **ImageMagick**, omit the word `magick` from the command.

---

As a quick test for blocks of solid colour, you could crop the image into 20x20 sub-images like this:

[image]

Then count the number of tiles where the variance is zero, i.e. the block is an absolutely solid colour. That will give an answer between 0 (meaning very likely a photo) and 400 (meaning very likely a solid block of colour). Count tiles with zero variance like this:

```
magick IMAGE -crop 20x20@ -format "%[standard-deviation]\n" info: | grep -c "^0$"
```

Your logo returns 199 on this measure and your photo returns 0.